# Unity Particle not visible inside an object with vertexlit blended shader

Tags: unity, shaders, particles

I'm developing a game with unity and I'm using a sphere with a texture on it as skybox in my game to fade 2 skyboxes when its the sunset or the sunrise. But my clouds work with a particle system and when the sphere is active, the clouds are not visible, how could I fix this? (The clouds are active on both images)

[image]

[image: ity]

Comment: First suspect is the depth buffer. What happens if you disable depth writes in your sky sphere shader? Also check the position of your sky sphere shader in the render queue vs your particle shader and sky box. It sounds like you want it to render in between those two, rather than after both.

Comment: What about ordering layers?